# Bot Telegram with Google Script- Wrong response from the webhook: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: bots, telegram, unauthorized

I set webHook with this function in google script

```
function setWebhook() {
var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

where telegram url contains telegram token and web AppUrl is google script exec url.
When i try to get webhook info with funtion

```
function getWebhookinfo() {
var url = telegramUrl + "/getWebhookInfo";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I receive this error message:

```
[20-12-22 10:41:23:115 CET] {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://script.google.com/macros/s/___________________________/exec","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"last_error_date":1608570964,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 401 Unauthorized","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"172.217.17.78"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, please check you deployment config: run by your name and allow access to everyone:

[image]

Also check this https://gist.github.com/manzoorwanijk/ee9ed032caedf2bb0c83dea73bc9a28e

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. This ( [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htfsW.png) ) is the correct configuration. 401 Unauthorized means it does not get access to your Google account. There is a button after you set the previous configuration to ask for the authority.